# Performance issue in continous ajax requests?

Tags: php, ajax

I created a ajax chat application something like this to check & get messages every second. and it works fine.

```
  function get_messages(user_id) {
    $.ajax({
      type    : "POST",
      url     : "messages/get_messages", 
      cache   : false,
      data    : {
        user_id : user_id 
      },
      success : function(data) {
        if(data != '') {
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          var messages = obj.messages;
        }
      }
    });
    setTimeout(function() { get_messages(user_id) }, 1000);
  }
```

My question is, When lot of people use this application a lot to Ajax requests to server every second, is there any performance issue or server issue in doing like this, . What is the best practice for doing this ??

Thank you for your valuable suggestions :)

Comment: Short answer yes. There will be a big performace issue as you are creating an HTTP request each second for each user. Consider using Sockets if you can.

Comment: Seconding Leeish on sockets, but if that's not possible make sure that your json feeds are being created from memchache or similar, are written as html so they're also cachable. Identify "expensive" parts of the workflow (database IO etc) and minimize what you send

Comment: It is not a simple question. It depends on the number of connected user. 1 ajax call per second is not a problem if you have 1à users "connected", but it can be a big problem if you have 1000 users or more "connected" to the tchat.

Comment: i'll recommend socket either. and for that you may want to try pusher.com

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do chats like this is having the "chat window" properly said as an `<iframe>` with a permanent connection to a script that will remain running and feeding the client with the new messages so you don't have to overwhelm the server with AJAX requests. This can be achieved by calling a `ob_flush()` (just to make sure) and `flush()` after printing new stuff, causing the client to receive the updates immediately. But first you have to prepare the PHP to behave properly by doing some settings:

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'off');
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
set_time_limit(0);
```

If you are going to use sessions, don't forget sessions are locked to prevent concurrent writes, so after gathering the information you need from `$_SESSION` you must release the session by using `session_write_close()` otherwise the user will be unable to post messages etc.

Your script should also check for inactivity and output something to the client if the chat window remain idle for more than a couple minutes. It prevents the connection from being terminated by the browser. It doesn't have to be anything visual, something commented like `<!-- keep alive -->` will do.

Now, where you gonna get the new messages from? There are a couple options for doing that:

1. Sockets. You can have this Chat Server application running in server-side that all the Chat Window PHP scripts will connect to to be fed with the new chat lines. When a user submit a new message, its sent to the Chat Server and it broadcast to the Chat Window scripts. This Chat Server can safely be written in PHP too!
2. A file. The easiest way. Every Chat Window PHP script open this same file for read-only, and `fseek()` to its end. Loops checking if its `!feof()` a couple times per second to read the new lines from it, if theres any. When a user send a new message you just have append this message to the file and the trick is done.
3. SQL. Not recommended because every Chat Window PHP script will open a new connection to the RDBMS and eventually will reach its limit, but you can try SQLite that don't use RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular Ajax/Php for this task is not preferable. As you stated that what if there is alot of users, each user will query the database every second.

This puts too much overload on your server and the users will not have realtime communication with each other.

I would suggest you to use node.js for this task. To make it cross-browser compatible you need to use a framework of node.js which is socket.io

So the final verdict, use node.js

You can learn node.js
http://www.nodebeginner.org/

There are very good tutorials in the web.
lynda.com has also very good tutorial on node.js